# How to fix No module named 'PolynomialRegression' on Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, regression, polynomials

I am trying to import PolynomialRegression as below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import solve, inv
import PolynomialRegression as pr
```

But I see below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PolynomialRegression'
```

Did anyone face to this error and how to fix it?

Comment: with !pip freeze , pls see if `PolynomialRegression` is installed. if not found then it needs to be installed.

Comment: Yeah, I installed it before posting the question but did not work.